# In a Tableau calculated field how can I check if a record exists that matches my parameters

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table like this (but with many more columns):

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Country        |        Year      |       Sales      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          US         |        2018      |        50        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          UK         |        2018      |        10        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          US         |        2019      |        40        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          US         |        2020      |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I have a dashboard that allows users to choose two parameters, Country and Year, and then it displays some sales data and charts. I want to show a warning if the user chooses a country and year combination that does not exist, such as "UK" and "2019"

I have tried making a calculated field using IF/THEN to return a warning text string, but I can't figure out how to check if a record rather than value exists.

`IF ISNULL([Sales]) THEN "No record exists" END`  Does not work because it returns that warning for a selection of "US" and "2020" parameters.

Comment: Instead of showing a warning, why not disable the null combination from showing? This can be achieved by right-clicking on the filter and selecting "Only Relevant Values"

Comment: @Bob, because the combination could be valid for some of the other charts on the dashboard. Not everything has the year parameter applied as a filter.

Comment: This can be achieved using a separate sheet where you drag a calculated field onto text. This calculated field would work in relation to your parameter when it is not null throw nothing but when null add some text in red or yellow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
IF COUNT(1) THEN "No records exist" END
```